# Using playwright for Python, how do I wait for two different selectors/handles at the same time and take the first successful match?

Tags: python, playwright, webautomation, playwright-python

using Playwright for Python, I need to catch if a page displays a winner **or** a loser message.

I can wait for a winner message to appear like this:

```
new_selector = "text=Your are a winner"
page.wait_for_selector(new_selector)
handle = query_selector(new_selector)
# do something with handle
```

But what can I do to wait for two different things? (Not only text but any kind of selector)

I could try an endless loop:

```
new_selector1 = "text=Your are a winner"
new_selector2 = "text=Better luck next time"

while True:
    handle = query_selector(new_selector1)
    if handle:
        break  
    handle = query_selector(new_selector2)
    if handle:
        break   
    time.sleep(0.25) 
    # write my own timeout here

# do something with handle
```

But is there something in playwright that allows me to **wait for two handles**
and take the **first match**?

Comment: A link would be nice, never heard of it.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to have intentionally nondeterministic or conditional tests like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass both selectors separated by a comma. [Ref](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#selecting-elements-matching-one-of-the-conditions).

```
new_selector = "text=Your are a winner, text=Better luck next time"
handle = query_selector(new_selector)
```